# Visual Studio 2013 saving and building before publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I recently formatted my computer and then reinstalled visual studio 2013 (I previously had VS 2012). I used to be able to right click on a specific aspx page and then publish that individual page with ought having to publish the entire site. Now, I need to publish the entire site just to reflect the change on one page and it's also not saving on publish. So, I believe what I'm asking is how to automatically build and save when I try to publish an individual page? Thanks, Chris.